# How was the skewness formula made/derived?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, skewness

The skewness formula that shows up when I Google it is:
[image: Skewness Formula]

I know what each of these values are individually, but I’m having a hard time seeing intuitively why this specific formula give a value for skewness, especially why parts of it are being cubed.

I also am curious how this formula was derived, and if it has any practical use.

Comment: The population skewness is usually defined as $\mathbb E\left[\left(\dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}  \right)^{3} \right]$ so rescaled and relocated to give $\mathbb E\left[\left(\dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}  \right)^{1} \right]=0$ and $\mathbb E\left[\left(\dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}  \right)^{2} \right]=1$.

Comment: @Glen_b - OK - I see that now

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56689 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159098 *inter alia.*